# How to select attributes in XML based on an ID?

Tags: php, xml, xml-attribute

I am trying to get a group of attributes from an XML file based on the ID.  I have looked around and haven't found a solution that works.

Here is my XML:

```
<data>
<vico>2</vico>
<vis>
<vi>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Vill1</name>
    <att>2</att>
    <hp>100</hp>
    <xp>10</xp>
</vi>
<vi>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Vill2</name>
    <att>3</att>
    <hp>120</hp>
    <xp>12</xp>
</vi>
</vis>
</data>
```

What I am looking to do is create a script that takes the value of vico and does mt_rand(0,vico) (Already created this part of the code), and based on the number that comes up, it pulls that node.

For instance, if the number is 2, I would like it to pull all of the attributes where the id in the xml file is 2.  I am thinking I have to make the ID a parent of the other attributes, but I am not sure. For the life of me I can't figure this out.  I also want to make sure this is even possible before I invest anymore time.

I do realize this can be done very easily with mySQL but I have chose not to do it that way for portability as I am working off a thumb drive.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Working code for pulling based on ID:

```
         $xml = simplexml_load_file("vi.xml")
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");


     $vc = $xml->vico;
     $select = mt_rand()&$vc;
     if ($select == 0) {
     $select = $select + 1;
     }

     $result = $xml->xpath("/data/vis/vi/id[.='".$select."']/parent::*");
if ($result) {
$node = $result[0];
$name = $node->name;
$att = $node->att;
$hp = $node->hp;
$xp = $node->xp  ;
} else {
// nothing found for this id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xpath to retrieve the node where id=your value (it is based on the value).

```
$result = $xml->xpath("/data/vis/vi/id[.='".$select."']/parent::*");
if ($result) {
   $node = $result[0];
   $name = $node->name;
   $att = $node->att;
   $hp = $node->hp;
   $xp = $node->xp  ;
} else {
   // nothing found for this id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SimpleXML:

```
$name = $xml->vis->vi[$vico]->name;
$att  = $xml->vis->vi[$vico]->att;
$hp   = $xml->vis->vi[$vico]->hp;
$xp   = $xml->vis->vi[$vico]->xp;
```

Comment: I think it has to be a loop.  I want to pull the 4 attributes that are lead by the ID.

Comment: @Rudenate3 If every `<id>` column is auto incrementing, you can easily do it this way (remember that the first row is `0`).

Comment: @Rudenate3 Fixed it=). Remember that vico must be `vico - 1`

Comment: I think maybe I wasn't clear haha.  I think your solution will work if I move the ID to the parent location.  I'll add the current code to the top...